# CronJobs on OSX Catalina not executing

Tags: macos, cron

I am aware apple has deprecated cron in favor of `launchd`. I want to use cron jobs over `launchd` because `launchd` does not provide the same time scheduling functionality as cron.

- I have enabled my `usr/sbin/cron` to have full disk access and I have my `crontab` on my root user with a simple job `* * * * * echo "test"` in order to verify if cron is executing or not.
- I have checked my root mail and user mail, then specified cron to mail out to a separate email with no luck.
- I have also checked my `cron.deny` and `at.deny` files to find only Guest is unable to execute cron jobs.
- I then created a `cron.allow` and `at.allow` files and added my user and root user to those files, still with no luck.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for getting cron jobs to execute on OSX Catalina? I am about to uninstall Catalina and install Ubuntu on the spare Mac Mini I'm using because this is so difficult to get running. Any suggestions much appreciated.

doing a `sudo crontab -l | pbcopy` has no output,

however doing a `sudo crontab -l` outputs this:

`* * * * * echo "test"`

I have to add `sudo` because the cron jobs are under the root user.

I am now able to see errors properly - my machine did not have any cronlogs, and did not have normal cron behavior of sending output to mail.

My work around was simply to create a txt file and log to it like so.

```
* * * * * pathtojob >> pathtologfile 2>&1
```

the `>>` indicates appending to a log file while the `2>&1` indicates to write standard out and error to that file. Thank you to those who helped me trouble shoot this.

Comment: Please run `crontab -l | pbcopy` then click `edit` under your question and paste it in. Select with mouse and click `{}` in Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code. Thank you.

Comment: crontab -l | pbcopy has no output, however crontab -l does. Added the information to the question

Comment: The output is in your clipboard... ready to paste.

Comment: Have you restarted your machine since adding the crontab entries? I don't think `crond` even starts if there is nothing to do at boot time.

Comment: I have restarted my machine - still with no luck

Comment: Is your `crond` even running? `sudo ps -aef | grep cron`

Comment: This responds with the test job running - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for errors in /var/log/cron. There might be an error there. Also are you sure the test echo script is working fine? Try executing it manually as well. It is better to redirect the output of cron job to a file. This way you can track if cron job is running by checking if the file is being populated.

Comment: there is no cron in /var/log on my machine - is there a reason this is the case? Also how could I direct the output to a specific file instead?

Comment: As cron has been deprecated, the default logging might not be available for cron in OSX. However, to direct the output to a specific file, you can use the following `* * * * * echo "test" > cron_output.log`

Comment: I created a txt file on my desktop, had the cronjob write to it and I see...TEST!!! Changing the crontab to be >> instead of > to overwrite. Thank you! I would upvote your answer but alas I don't have 15 reputation.