# crontab job installing but not executing on my MAC

Tags: python, macos, cron, launchd

I have been trying to run a python script on my MAC every day automatically with no success so far. I failed using `launched`, and I am now trying to use `crontab` to see if I am luckier that way.

The script runs OK without using `crontab`:

```
cd '/Users/johnEd/Documents/code/myFolder' && '/usr/local/bin/python3' 'myfile.py'
```

I have been able to install a new `crontab`

```
20 10 * * * cd '/Users/johnEd/Documents/code/myFolder' && '/usr/local/bin/python3' 'myfile.py'
```

The crontab lists when I do `crontab -l` but it does not seem to run at all

Comment: Are you on the same user in the console both times? Are you sure it doesn't run and not just error when running? -> Add output redirection to a file, set it to 5 minutes from now, see if the file is created and with what contents

Comment: Remember that cron uses different PATH than your normal user environment. Examining stdout and stderr outputs from your cron line should help. But you can also add `echo $PATH > /tmp/cronpath.txt` to cron and just see the PATH for yourself

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't run? Please [edit] to provide debugging details. Perhaps see also [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) for general troubleshooting tips, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755352/cronjobs-on-osx-catalina-not-executing for some Mac-specific guidance. (Also, what's with the wacky quoting?)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the whole folder onto `/opt` and the file is now being executed by crontab

Thanks for your help everybody!